# how to create a bookshelf kind which is in ibook app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I want to create a book shelf which is similar to ibook app where i put some books or pdf  in shelf and click on  that the book or pdf should launch.so can anyone tel me  how to implement or any sample code is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is custom interface.
Main container is a scrollView, it will contain repeatable pattern of your bookshelf. Then you need to put some UIView in proper coordinates, which will contain your book cover images.
Other part of application is a book reader, you can use some framework, something like FastPdfKit or another.

Comment: how abt using tableview???is it not a good idea??

Comment: because you can customize tableview cell, you also can use tableview.